# Tornado does not handle node-http-proxy websockes on linux

Tags: python, node.js, websocket, tornado, node-http-proxy

If I start a server `python wsserver.py` and then run `python wsclient.py --host localhost --port 8888` the tornado server and client behave as expected.

However, if I start up a proxy server as well: `node node_modules/http-proxy/bin/node-http-proxy --port 8889 --host localhost --target localhost:8888` then `python wsclient.py --host localhost --port 8889` does connect, but no messages get passed.

This works fine on Max osx however fails on ubuntu and centos.

wsserver.py:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
  def open(self):
    print "opened a new websocket"
    listeners.append(self)
    print listeners

  def on_message(self, message):
     self.write_message(u"You Said: " + message)
     print ("in on_message " + message)

  def on_close(self):
    print 'connection closed'
    listeners.remove(self)


def main():
    application = tornado.web.Application([(r'/ws', WSHandler)])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

wsclient.py:

```
# must pip install websocket-client first

from argparse import ArgumentParser

def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--port', type=int, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--host', required=True)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    from websocket import create_connection
    ws = create_connection("ws://%s:%s/ws" %(args.host, args.port))
    print "Sending 'Hello, World'..."
    ws.send("Hello, World")
    print "Sent"
    print "Reeiving..."
    result =  ws.recv()
    print "Received '%s'" % result
    ws.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How do I debug this?

versions:

- node: 0.9.9
- http-proxy; 0.10.2
- python: 2.7
- tornado: 2.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could u try that with node v0.6.x pls?
As far as i know node-http-proxy has some header problems with websockets since never node version (not sure with which version it started). Im sure with a lower node version u should be ok.

Comment: Node v0.6.12 works on ubuntu and centos. However, all versions of node work when the proxy is running on Mac osx